# Format for Passing a Collection to a Method

Tags: c#, collections

I'm using an API that has a method that requires this type of argument:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<GenericTickType> genericTickList
```

How do I instantiate an object for that argument?  Here's what I've tried but it keeps saying that the method call has some invalid arguments.

```
List<TickType> ticks_to_get = new List<TickType> { TickType.Price };
```

I've tried instantiating a Collection directly instead of a List and that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are GenericTickType and TickType two different type or is this a typo? What is their relationship (one derives from the other)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I've tried instantiating a Collection directly instead of a List and that doesn't seem to work."

What error do you get? You can definitely create an instance of `Collection<T>` directly, it is not an abstract class and it has several public constructors, including one that's parameter-less. You can do this, for example:

```
var values = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<int> { 1,2,3,4 };
```

I noticed your sample code has a `GenericTickType` and a `TickType`. Is this a mistake or do you actually have two classes? You said it's an enum (which one?), so one cannot possibly derive from the other. If they are two enum types, `Collection<GenericTickType>` and `Collection<TickType>` are two different classes and one is not assignable to the other.

Now, if `TickType` is *castable* to `GenericTickType` (and they probably are if they are both enums, and assuming they share the same numeric values), you still cannot cast `Collection<TickType>` to `Collection<GenericTickType>`. There's no contra/co-variance in C# for most classes yet (coming in C# 4). But you could cast *each* `TickType` by doing something like this:

```
List<GenericTickType> list = new List<GenericTickType> { (GenericTickType)TickType.Price };
list.Add((GenericTickType)TickType.Price); // add more...
Collection<GenericTickType>genericTicks = new Collection<GenericTickType>(list);
```

If you already have a `List<TickType>` and have access to C# 3.0 and LINQ, you can do this:

```
List<TickType> ticks = new List<TickType> { TickType.Price };
list.Add(TickType.Price); // add more...
List<GenericTickType> castedList = ticks.Cast<GenericTickType>().ToList();
Collection<GenericTickType>genericTicks = new Collection<GenericTickType>(castedList);
```

This uses the LINQ `Cast<T>()` and `ToList<T>()` extension methods to cast *each* `TickType` in the original list to `GenericTickType` and creating a new `List<GenericTickType>` which is used to instantiate the `Collecion<GenericTickType>`. (I avoided using `var` so you could see the types in each step).

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a `List<>` as a `Collection<>`

Maybe you have problems with covariance/contravariance? You have to do the cast on your own:

```
List<TickType> ticks_to_get = new Collection<TickType> { TickType.Price };

genericTickList = (Collection<GenericTickType>) ticks_to_get;
```

Look at Dave Bauman's answer ... unless TickType.Price doesn't return an object of type TickType it will not work

**EDIT:** Since GenericTickType is an enum - which API are you using? Is it of your company - can you change it? It seems to be strange that you are asked to pass a collection of enum values. See, if you can change the enum to a [flagged enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) ... and then pass the required values by combining them with the or-operator.

Comment: List<T> cannot be cast to a Collection<T>

Comment: I get an error: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TickType>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<GenericTickType>'

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of `GenericTickType`? Is it an enum or class? I am assuming enum. If that is the case, modify your code as such:

```
Collection<GenericTickType> ticks_to_get = new Collection<GenericTickType>() { GenericTickType.Price };
```

The above works on 3.5 framework.

Comment: It's an enum.  The solution you provided gives me the same error message as the original.

Comment: Yes, you can't cast a enum of type TickType to one of type GenericTickType.

Comment: Right. You would have to use GenericTickType instead of TickType. it is an invalid cast. I can revise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use {} to initialize a Collection.  You can do something like this, however:

```
List<TickType> ticks_to_get = 
    new List<TickType>( new TickType[] { TickType.Price });
```

or

```
List<TickType> ticks_to_get = new List<TickType>();
ticks_to_get.Add(TickType.Price);
```

Comment: Actually, it's in C# 3.0, e.g. VS2008 targetting fx 2.0